# Adding EKEvents in bucle from start date to end date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, ekevent

I have this data:

```
NSString* startDate = @"11/27/2015";
NSString* endDate = @"12/02/2015";
NSString* startHour = @"10:00";
NSString* endHour = @"15:00";
NSString* title = @"Event Title";
```

And I want to add the event to the calendar, from 11/27/2015 to 12/02/2015 from 10:00 to 15:00.

Have I to add multiple EKEvent, one per day? Or there is a way to create one EKEvent who describes all?

Answer (score 0):

```
try below code...
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
   // Create a new event object.
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: eventStore];

    // Set the event title.
    event.title = eventMessage;

    // Set its calendar.


    NSString *identifier=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"calenderId"];
     // NSLog(@"cal identifier: %@",identifier);
    event.calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:identifier];

    //set Alarm
    NSTimeInterval secondsInOneHours = 1 * 60 * 60;

    NSDate *dateOneHoursAhead = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInOneHours];

    // Set the start and end dates to the event.
    event.startDate = eventDate;
    event.endDate = dateOneHoursAhead; //

NSError *error;
    if ([eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&error]) {

      / NSLog(@"Event Added");
    }
    else{
         An error occurred, so log the error description.
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: In that way I can add an Event. But the Event that I want occurs in a repetitive way in more than one day. I dont know if I have to add only one customized Event, or I have to add one single Event for each day. I think that the best way is to create one event, but I didn't find info about that.

Comment: using above you can add many event in one day their is no limit. if you add event on same time and date still their is no issue. other wise you can get all event for your calendar and check with current event, if conflict occur just notify user. i 've done this my application

Answer (score 0):

I have to use EKRecurrenceRule class.

```
EKEvent* event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

EKRecurrenceRule* recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily interval:1 end:[EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:eventEndDate]];
         event.recurrenceRules = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recurrenceRule,nil];
```